# onTextChanged, cant get it to work right

Tags: java, android, search, android-edittext

Hey guys I need my search function to act like the contacts. I'm retrieving my list of participants from a server and I rebuild it when the user searches to get there results. Hoover i can only get it to work when they enter their full first name..  Let me show you my code. Ive tried a lot of combinations. any idea? This is a donation app for the child hunger alliance. =]

this is just in a for loop to add each name fyi

```
if (searchQ.contains(child.first_name.toLowerCase()) 
|| searchQ.matches(child.last_name.toLowerCase()) {

 id = child.id;
 addChildToList(child); 

 }

 if (searchQ.matches("")){
    addChildToList(child);


 }
```

here is my textwatcher

```
public void searchChild(){
    final EditText ET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);


    // create the TextWatcher
    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {



            // Rebuilds the list
            String searchQ = ET.getText().toString();
             getChildrenListSearch(searchQ);


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            // Remove rows that do no match
            TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.childList); 
            tl.removeAllViews();


        }
    };

    //we must add the textWatcher to our EditText
    ET.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other way around...

```
if (searchQ.contains(child.first_name.toLowerCase()) 
    || searchQ.matches(child.last_name.toLowerCase()) {

     id = child.id;
     addChildToList(child); 

     }
```

to this...

```
if (child.first_name.toLowerCase().contains(searchQ) 
        || searchQ.matches(child.last_name.toLowerCase()) {

         id = child.id;
         addChildToList(child); 

         }
```

Comment: what error does it give you? Also you understand why it needs to be this way right? you are looking to see if the search term partially matches the child name not the other way around

Comment: nvm your cbode worked fine just had to switch up a few things, and I didn't look at it that way! I see now!  Is there a way to have it equalIgnoreCase and contains at the same time without me writing another function?

Comment: just use searchQ.toLowerCase()